# Add other object to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I made a small code

```
NSArray* _options = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIImage    imageNamed:@"2"],@"img",name,@"text"
                                   , nil],nil];
```

Now, I want add other object to _options. What should i do?
I make more test but no success.
Thank for all

Answer (score 2):

you can use `[NSArray arrayByAddingObject:]`

```
_options = [_options arrayByAddingObject:object];
```

or change `_options` to `NSMutableArray`

```
NSMutableArray *_options = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIImage    imageNamed:@"2"],@"img",name,@"text"
                                   , nil],nil];
[_options addObject:object];
```

and you may want to use modern syntax

```
NSMutableArray *_options = [@[@{@"img":[UIImage imageNamed:@"2"],@"text":name}] mutableCopy];
[_options addObject:object];
```

Answer (score 2):

NSArray does not allow any changes to be made; you can use an `NSMutableArray` instead like this:

```
NSMutableArray *mutable = [_options mutableCopy];

[mutable addObject:yourObject];
```

NSDictionary is same in that it can't be mutated.

Answer (score 1):

First, create an NSMutableArray, as you can make changes to it as you see fit later throughout your code:

```
NSMutableArray *newOptions = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[newOptions setArray:_options];

[newOptions addObject:yourObject];
```

Comment: `NSArray` does not have method `addObject:` I downvote it because this is wrong answer.

Comment: I want to downvote it again. `newOptions = _options` doesn't magically change `_options` to `NSMutableArray`

Comment: another downvote, you should use `setArray:` not `addObject:`

Answer (score 1):

You can't add objects to a [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html), to do so, you need a [NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

However, you can add objects to NSArray when creating it with : [arrayWithObjects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/arrayWithObjects%3a)